# Read a column from a file and append a specific column of another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have two files as such:

fileA:

```
Name,Site Name,Product UPEI,Product Name,NMS Flag,Product Model, SW
```

FileB:

```
NE_Name       SW   
ABC           4.4
ASD           4.3
...           ...
```

Note that fileA just consists of a single line and it has several headers (eg, Name, Site Name etc.). Whereas, fileB has 2 fields with huge number of lines.

I want to combine these 2 files as such:

Output file:

```
Name,Site Name,Product UPEI,Product Name,NMS Flag,Product Model, SW
ABC,,,,,,4.4
ASD,,,,,,4.3
```

Thus, output file would have all the headers present in fileA and would expand the fields: 'Name' (with the 'NE_Name' values fetched from fileB) and 'SW' (with the 'SW' values fetched from fileB).

How can I get this output file from the 2 input files mentioned above?

Comment: Could you care for a little better explanation. `cat fileA` and paste the output; `cat fileB` and paste the output & the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{nf=NF-1; print $0; FS=" "} \
         NR>2{printf("%s%.*s%s\n",$1,nf,",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",$2)}' fileA fileB

Name,Site Name,Product UPEI,Product Name,NMS Flag,Product Model, SW
ABC,,,,,,4.4
ASD,,,,,,4.3
```

Crucial part is `printf` where we print first and third fields from fileB separated by `,` which number is taken from first file as `nf=NF-1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. However, I would like to ask some questions to understand your command better:
1- Why you set 'nf=NF-1'? Why not to NF directly?
2- I guess, 'NR==1' phrase cause the firs line operation to be handled in fileA (this file has just 1 record) and 'NR>2' phrase cause the second line to be handled in fileB since it has 2 records. Am I correct?
3- Can you describe what this phrase do exactly: 'printf("%s%.*s%s\n",$1,nf,",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",$2'?
Thanks...

Comment: @Murat 1) The point is to take number of delimiters `,` from fileA, and use it in fileB, so that if you add another header (field) to fileA it will be automatically transformed to fileB. To achieve that I use `NF` parameter which returns number of fields in the row, however number of delimiters is `NF-1`. 2) Yes `NR==1` corresponds to fileA, `NR==2` would be first line in fileB, but we don't need that line, so we skip to `NR>2` - line third and rest (line 2 in fileB and rest). 3) `printf` prints `$1` then very long string of `,` cut to `NF-1` characters, then `$2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The last questions: 1- Could you please describe the logic of the phrase ' FS=" " ' located in the first line of your command? 
2- What is the meaning of the phrase: ' %.*s '?
Thanks...

Comment: @Murat `FS=" "` sets field separator to space and `%.*s` prints string cut to defined number of characters. Try `printf "%.*s\n" 3 "abcdef"` in bash.

Comment: I think you set the field separator to space for fileB because it has columns seperated by tabs? I was thinking that file separator for fileA is comma so I was wondering why you set the file separator to space. So, you just printed the whole line of fileA and then set the file separator to space to be able to separate the columns of fileB. Right?

Comment: @Murat I set `FS` to `,` for fileA and then go back to space for fileB.

Comment: Alright, everything is clear now :) Thank you very much for your prompt help.

Answer (score 2):

```
tail -n+2 fileB | sed -r 's/[[:space:]]+/,,,,,,/' | cat fileA - > Output
```

### Explanations

`tail -n +2 fileB` writes the end of fileB, starting at the second line, since we want to ignore the first line.

`sed`, using `-r, --regexp-extended` (for the `+` meta-character meaning '*at least one*') replaces the first group of spacing characters by the expected amount of commas as of your example.

`cat` finally concatenates fileA and the data received from `sed` through the pipe, referred to as `-`, and writes it to `stdout`, which is redirected to the `Output` file as of your request.

### Limitations

Will not work if there are space characters in NE_Name or SW columns.

Comment: Your solution without tail and the GNU -r option `sed -e '1d' -e 's/[[:space:]]*[[:space:]]/,,,,,,/' fileB | cat fileA - > Output`

Comment: Clever use of `1d`, didn't cross my mind. is there any reason to use `[[:space:]]*[[:space:]]` instead of `[[:space:]][[:space:]]*` ? I would have assumed that the second option fails faster for non-space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` approach:

```
$ sed 's/   */,,,,,,,/;/NE_/d' fileA fileB
Name,Site Name,Product UPEI,Product Name,NMS Flag,Product Model, SW
ABC,,,,,,,4.4
ASD,,,,,,,4.3
```

The 1st `sed` command replaces 3 or more spaces with 7 commas and the 2nd removes any line matching `NE_`.